# How to specify an asynchronous request in API JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send to server (php) a request AJAX from an api javascript:

JS File :

```
var commit = new Object();

commit.id= this.id;
commit.action = this.doCommit;
commit.vrp= this.vrp;
$.post(this.ajaxURL, commit);
```

with this code i can send a request but in mode asynchroun. I searched on internet and I found a solution :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.ajaxURL,
    data: commit,
    async:false
});
```

I don't know if it is the best solution, or I can precise async:false in a  $.post request, if yes , how ?.

Comment: Do you realize that post is just a wrapper for $.ajax? Use $.ajax, but in the end you really should not use synchronous requests.

Comment: Why do you want a synchronous call? Unless you have a concrete reason, you should use asynchronous calls I guess.

Answer (score 0):

So you do or you do not want to send the request asynchronously? The question seems to be confusing for me. But by default, `$.ajax({...` is always async, and $.post is just a shorthand way to write a simple post ajax request, which is also async. If you use the `async:false`, you are telling the javascript to not continue to execute the next line of code until the request finishes.